# I'd like to embed an image in my emails

Tags: c#, css, image, email, embed

I've been trying out many different things, but I just can't seem to figure out how to embed an image in my code. My plan is to send mails with an image in the string body. The image is saved in the content folder.

```
mm.Subject = "CompanyName ";
string body = "Dear " + CustomerMasterObj.CustomerName + ", \n";
                    body += "\n";
                    body += "\n";    
                    body += EmailTemplateObj.EmailMsg;
                    body += "\n";
                    body += Userurl;
                    body += "\n";
                    body += "Thank you in advance. \n";
                    body += "\n";
                    body += " Yours sincerely, \n";
                    body += "\n";
                    body += "John Doe \n";
                    mm.Body = body;    
                    mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML to add a `<img>` tag but that would mean converting your image to base64 or hosting it:

Here is some pseudo-code to achieve so:

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage
   {
     IsBodyHtml = true,
     Subject = "CompanyName",
   };
string body = "HTML OPENING TAG .... YOUR CONTENT";
body += "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes("path")) + "\" alt=\"myimage\" />";
body += "MORE HTML + HTML CLOSING TAG";
mm.Body = body;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following were LinkedResource object was used because in some cases on mobile email applications without LinkedResource images did not appear for the receiver of the message.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace PayneInMyButt
{
    public class EmailImage
    {
        public void DemoForImage()
        {
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                mail.From = new MailAddress("TODO");
                mail.To.Add("TODO");
                mail.Subject = "This is an email";

                AlternateView PlainMessage = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("Hello, plain text", null, 
                    "text/plain");

                AlternateView HtmlMessage = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
                    "This is an automated email, please do not respond<br><br>This is a test <br>" + 
                    "<span style=\"font-weight: bold; padding-left: 20px;padding-right:5px\">Some bold text</span>" + 
                    "Non bold<br><span style=\"font-weight: bold; padding-left: 5px;padding-right:5px\">Second line</span>" + 
                    "This is Kate below<br><span style=\"font-weight: bold; padding-left: 70px;padding-right:5px\">" + 
                    "<img src=cid:Image1>", null, "text/html");

                LinkedResource Logo = new LinkedResource(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
                    "LogoImage.jpg"), 
                    "image/jpeg");

                Logo.ContentId = "Image1";

                mail.AlternateViews.Add(PlainMessage);
                mail.AlternateViews.Add(HtmlMessage);
                using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("TODO"))
                {
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```